# The function "Muxer.make()" in the io.humble video library is quite slow

Tags: java, video-encoding

I recently use this example ([RecordAndEncodeVideo.java](https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video/blob/master/humble-video-demos/src/main/java/io/humble/video/demos/RecordAndEncodeVideo.java))  in io.humble library 
to create my own video recording application, but I found that this line "final Muxer muxer = Muxer.make(filename, null, formatname)" took a quite long time (>10 seconds), I cannot figure why this happened. It seems that hardly no one ask this question before. Did I do something wrong? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Slow compared to _what_? You can definitely figure out what happens by looking at the code.

Comment: I added the time counter for this line of code , it averagely need more than 10 seconds  to complete. I don't know if this is normal.